# Python: defining a variable in callback function...not sure where

Tags: python, ftp

Excerpt:

```
file = open("D:\\DownloadFolder\\test.mp3", "wb")

def callback(data):
    file.write(data)
    sizeWritten += len(data)
    print(sizeWritten)

connect.retrbinary('RETR test.mp3', callback)
print("completed")
```

Python obviously complains that I didn't define `sizeWritten`, but I'm not sure where I should define it. If I put `sizeWritten = 0` before the function it still gives an error `local variable 'sizeWritten referenced before assignment`. How should I do this?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is okay for `sizeWritten` to be a global (e.g. there is only ever going to be *one* callback active at a time), you can mark it as such in your function:

```
file = open("D:\\DownloadFolder\\test.mp3", "wb")
sizeWritten = 0

def callback(data):
    global sizeWritten
    file.write(data)
    sizeWritten += len(data)
    print(sizeWritten)
```

and any assignments to the name in `callback` alter the global.

In Python 3, you can also use a closure, and the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def download(remote, local):
    file = open(local, "wb")
    sizeWritten = 0

    def callback(data):
        nonlocal sizeWritten
        file.write(data)
        sizeWritten += len(data)
        print(sizeWritten)

    connect.retrbinary('RETR ' + remote, callback)
    print("completed")
```

This encapsulates the `sizeWritten` and `file` objects in a local namespace, at least.

However, you could get the same information directly from the open `file` file object:

```
def callback(data):
    file.write(data)
    print(file.tell())
```